# RegExp_Extract everything before first dot in Google Data Studio

Tags: regex, google-analytics, looker-studio, re2

I'm trying to use Google Data Studio to build a dashboard of browser versions. The "*Browser Version*" field in Google Analytics has too much detail so I want to extract everything before the `.` in a version number. I've tried creating a new field with the following formula, but keep getting an error "`Could not parse formula`". I've tested this RegEx on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) and it seems to work so maybe I'm not understanding something about Google Data Studio?

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Browser Version,'^(.+?)\.')
```

Comment: Try `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Browser Version,'^.+?\.')` Is Browser Version a legal name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below regular expression. I believe the issue is because `(not set)` is also a possible value for the `Browser Version` dimension, so your regex must cater for that condition as well.

`REGEXP_EXTRACT(Browser Version,'^\\D*(\\d+)\\D*')`

Comment: Yes! I forgot about the (not set) value, which doesn't contain a period. It works perfectly now and shows me a series of "Major version numbers"

Comment: That's great. Feel free to mark this as the accepted answer if you think it'll be of use to others.